# Risk adjusted premium principle (subadditivity)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, risk-assessment

Define the premium for a risk $X\geq0$ as:

$$
π(X)=∫^∞_0(1−F_X(t))^{1/ρ}dt
$$

With $\rho\geq1$.

Let $X,Y\geq0$ two independent random variables. Prove or find a counterexample for:

$$
\pi(X+Y)\leq\pi(X)+\pi(Y)
$$

I've tried a lot of counterexamples, but any of them work. It looks that it actually works, but I don't know how to prove it. Please help!

UPDATE:

Stochastic Processes for Insurance and Finance (page 89)

Tomasz Rolski, Hanspeter Schmidli, V.

It is left to the reader as an exercise. So it is actually true. How to prove it?

https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=Mcivgw2meSYC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=risk+adjusted+premium+principle+subadditivity&source=bl&ots=cBWhS--SS1&sig=ACfU3U19BulMnxzNmUMRhugnUbBoQaO4vg&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4o-jRp9joAhUGSa0KHVtyCksQ6AEwCnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=risk%20adjusted%20premium%20principle%20subadditivity&f=false

Comment: Hi you can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266875/risk-adjusted-premium-principle

Comment: Yes, in that question they mention the property, but they doesn't prove it.

Comment: So look at this paper Wang S. S. (1996) Premium calculation by transforming the layer premium density, ASTIN. https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/astin-bulletin-journal-of-the-iaa/article/premium-calculation-by-transforming-the-layer-premium-density/BB0A337E5F9134AE0429A6CB47D17F7E often cited in theliterature